# Node JS - MongoDB - findAndModify is upating wrong object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have an issue in findAndModify method, I am trying update one record but it is always updating first record in the db.

AngularJS call:

```
$http.put('/fidlist/'+$scope.fid._id, $scope.fid)
.then(
function(response) {
refresh();
},
function(error) {
console.log("error -- "+error);
})
```

server.js

```
app.put('/fidlist/:id',function(req,res){
var id = req.params.id;
db.fidlist.findAndModify({
Query:{_id:mongojs.ObjectID(id)}, 
update:{$set: {fid:req.body.fid,description:req.body.description,release:req.body.release,status:req.body.status,nodeagent:req.body.nodeagent,nas:req.body.nas,cli:req.body.cli,clis:req.body.clis,webui:req.body.webui,webuis:req.body.webuis,tl1:req.body.tl1,tls:req.body.tls}},
new:true
}, function(err,doc){
res.json(doc);
});
});
```

Fiddler response:
[image]

Comment: what is db.fidlist and where it's defined?

Comment: As you can see here you can modify one object at a time if your fidlist is having array then you have to implement it differently . https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: Hi @YashGanatra, Thanks for the reply, fidlist is my db name and defined it in the server file `var db = mongojs('fidlist',['fidlist']);` - And I am trying to modify one object and I am passing the  object ID in the query and and fields in request body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
Query : {_id:mongojs.ObjectID(id)}
```

But it should be:

```
query : {_id:mongojs.ObjectID(id)}
```

As documented [in the fine manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#definition).